# How to make Q object expression in this case(filtering by ForeignKey field)?

Tags: django, django-orm

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class PostFollow(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

and from those model classes, I want to get posts that is not followed by some user.

Like this:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)

not_followed_post = Post.objects.filter(Q(pk__lte=1000) & ~Q(self__is_not_followed_by_user=user))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it more self-explaining when using `.exclude(..)`:

```
not_followed_post = Post.objects.exclude(
    postfollow__user=user
).filter(
    pk__lte=1000
)
```

The `.exclude(..)` will perform *universal quantification* in a *transparent* way.

I tink it is probably better to add explicit `related_name`s here, to make it easier to pinpoint where the relation is looking at. For example:

```
class PostFollow(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='postfollow'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='postfollow'
    )
```

The `pk__lte` is rather weird. Usually the `pk` is used only as an identifier. Making queries like `__lte` is of course possible, but rather uncommon.

Yes, `pk`s are typically "distributed" in creation order (given you do not specify an explicit one), so if you never assign expliclty, you could probably use it to obtain more recent records than a given record. But still I think it is a bit "risky" to start filtering in such way. If you for example later add *historical* data to the database, then these can (depending on how you insert the data) have higher `id`s, and thus show up in the results.